# Page to update mysql entry does not run sql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have three pages at the moment:

```
config.php: contains the configuration for mysql connection
list.php: lists entries in a mysql table
edit.php: edits a specific entry selected in list.php
```

config.php:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'server');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_NAME', 'database');
 
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

list.php:

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
    <title>Bienvenue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "select * from TABLE");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
        echo "<tr>
        <td><a href='edit.php?id=" . $row['IDCOLUMN'] . "' class='btn btn-success ml-3'>Modifier</a></td>
        <td>" . $row['column 1'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['column 2'] . "</td>
        </tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
        }

        mysqli_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
        ?>


  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

edit.php:

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

$resname_err = $rescity_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate new password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["nom_residence"]))){
        $resname_err = "Entrer le nom de la résidence.";     
    } elseif(empty(trim($_POST["ville_residence"]))){
        $rescity_err = "Entrer la ville de la résidence.";     
    }else{
        $resname1 = trim($_POST["nom_residence"]);
        $rescity1 = trim($_POST["ville_residence"]);
    }
        
    // Check input errors before updating the database
    if(empty($resname_err) && empty($rescity_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE residences SET RESIDENCE = ?, VILLE = ? WHERE residenceID = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $resname1, $rescity1, $id);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                header("location: list.php?=".$resname1.$rescity1);
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
        
    }
    
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
    <title>Bienvenue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($link, "select * from residences where residenceID=".$id);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $resname = $row['RESIDENCE'];
    $rescity = $row['VILLE'];

}

mysqli_close($link)

?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>modify entry</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>value name1</label>
            <input name="nom_residence" class="form-control <?php echo 
(!empty($resname_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $resname; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $resname_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>value name2</label>
            <input name="ville_residence" class="form-control <?php echo 
(!empty($rescity_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $rescity; ?>">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $rescity_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enregistrer">
            <a class="btn btn-link ml-2" href="list.php">Annuler</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My current problem is that the Mysql entry is never updated.
This section runs:

```
header("location: list.php?=".$resname1.$rescity1);
```

So I know every condition is met correctly
Note: I added this part to know their values when redirected to list.php:

```
.$resname1.$rescity1
```

I ran all the code inside a PHP shell and it worked perfectly.
Of course, I had to set the values resname1 and rescity1 manually, so I'm thinking it must be some formatting issue?

Comment: plz check id column name in update $sql in edit.php and also check it in list.php at href=edit.php?id=  be ause i think problem is different id column names used in list.php edit link and in edit.php

Comment: For starters, dump all your query parameters (`$resname1, $rescity1, $id`) and see if they actually contain what they should.

Comment: Does the `id` value persist when you submit the form? That is, is it included in your `PHP_SELF` or is it stripped from that?